# add a row at the end of a table with interop

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I want to add programmatically a row at the end of a table in PowerPoint with Interop.

I use :

```
myShape.Table.Rows.Add(index)
```

it works well to insert anywhere except at the last line.
As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/vba/word-vba/articles/rows-add-method-word) describes, you add a row before the line you give in index.

Do you know the way to add a row at the end of the table
(I have in mind to add a line  just before the last, copy the last to this one, and then clear the last, but there shall be a better way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply don't use an index at all, or use `-1` *which is the default value for the optional parameter*. Either of the following should work fine:

```
Dim newRow As PowerPoint.Row = slide.Shapes(1).Table.Rows.Add()
```

Or:

```
Dim newRow As PowerPoint.Row = slide.Shapes(1).Table.Rows.Add(-1)
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)